# Is it safe to add scripts dynamically to a site?

Tags: javascript, html, web

We are having an office debate about the following practice and want to get the opinions of the internet.

We are having issues with users upgrading their library and looking for a decent solution. Is the following process safe or does it present security vulnerabilities?

```
var s = document.createElement('script')
s.scr = "https://plugins.myplugin.com/latest_version_of_script.js"
document.body.appendChild(s)
```

Comment: Why not, the Client could do it too. Client-side JavaScript only affects the Client. The only time it could be an issue is if you programmed the backend wrong. Remember your site really lives on the backend.

Comment: How could it be security vulnerability? I would love to hear that funny stuff. Please share! There is zero difference in doing that and having a script tag other than some performance differences....

Comment: Chief dev says to "avoid inline scripts. It's actually bad security practice."